# Multiple footer rows in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can i display information in multiple rows in grid-view footer using code behind

for example

```
header1   header2           header3

 data        data              data

 data        data              data

             Amount:           value

             Shipping Cost:    value

             Total Amount:     value
```

How can i add Shipping cost and Total Amount in the footer

```
protected void gridinvoice_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    decimal Amount = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < gridinvoice.Rows.Count; y++)
    {
        Amount += Convert.ToDecimal(gridinvoice.Rows[y].Cells[4].Text);
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {  
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "Amount";
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = Amount.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: could you please include the footer template

Comment: hi theirs no footer template i just set ShowFooter="true"

Comment: Did you get any error? I though the cell index is wrong, as per your  example it contains 3 columns which become 0,1,2 for binding. `e.Row.Cells[1].Text ="Amount" `

Comment: No its just for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement you could try like this:

```
protected void gridinvoice_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    decimal Amount = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < gridinvoice.Rows.Count; y++)
    {
        Amount += Convert.ToDecimal(gridinvoice.Rows[y].Cells[4].Text);
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {  
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "Amount: <br/> Shipping Cost: <br/> Total Amount:";
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = Amount.ToString() +"<br/>"+shipping.ToString() +"<br/>" + total.ToString();
    }

}
```

Or you could Structure your footer on Aspx page using Controls and footer template and assign the value to the controls on code behind.

```
  protected void gridinvoice_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal Amount = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < gridinvoice.Rows.Count; y++)
        {
            Amount += Convert.ToDecimal(gridinvoice.Rows[y].Cells[4].Text);
        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {  
           Label lblamount = e.Row.FindControl("lblid") as Label;
           lblam.Text = Amount.ToString();
        }

    }
```